# Getting error while inserting data into database using Python and Django

Tags: python, django

I am getting below error while inserting data into database using Python and Django.

```
OperationalError at /insert/
no such table: bookingservice_service
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/insert/
Django Version: 1.11.2
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: bookingservice_service
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 328
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/opt/lampp/htdocs/carClinic',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
```

Here is my code:

bookingservice/models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from datetime import datetime

class Service(models.Model):
    """In this class the columns for service table has declared"""
    cname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_of_service = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    vechile_no = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    service_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Personal(models.Model):
    """In this class the columns for Person table has declared"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    driving_license = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

admin.site.register(Personal)
admin.site.register(Service)
```

My `views.py` file is given below.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.views.generic import View
from django.contrib.auth.forms import (UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm)
from bookingservice.models import Service, Personal

def booking(request):
    return render(request, 'bookingservice/booking.html', {})

def insert(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        company_name = request.POST.get('cname')
        vechicle_no = request.POST.get('vechileno')
        service_type = request.POST.get('sertype')
        s = Service( 
        cname=company_name, 
        vechile_no=vechicle_no, 
        service_type=service_type
        ) 
        s.save()
    return render(request, 'bookingservice/booking.html', {})

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'bookingservice/home.html', {})
```

I already migrated the models and its showing me the below messages.

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
  Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if your app `bookingservice` is inside `installed_apps` in `settings.py`. If not then add your app `bookingservice` in installed_apps.

In `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    ...
    'bookingservice',
]
```

Then again perform migrations again

```
manage.py makemigrations
```

and then

```
manage.py migrate
```

If your app is already inside `installed_apps` then perform

```
manage.py makemigrations bookingservice
```

and

```
manage.py migrate bookingservice
```